# 'Could not add Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face' Why can't I add this nuget to my Xamarin.Forms.iOS project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to work with facerecognition in xamarin forms by following these guides: 
https://blog.xamarin.com/building-smart-apps-with-microsoft-cognitive-services/
https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-facial-recognition-to-your-mobile-apps/

When I add the needed packages: `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face` and `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common` to my shared project it works but once I add them to my iOS project the `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face` does not get added with the following error message:

### Could not install package 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face 1.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have tried to install every version from it, all the way from 1.1.0 to 1.2.5.1.

I have the Newtonsoft.Json package installed as well as the Microsoft.Net.Http as well that is required.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Because the `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face` package does not contain any Xamarin compatible targets.

One way to work around this would be to pull the SDK down locally and reference in your project.

Comment: Ah alright! I have not done that before. So download it from here? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face/1.2.1.2 And add the file in Project -> Project.iOS -> ?

Comment: You could always try that. I was more referring to the Github project!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-Face-Windows

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the link. How do I add this to my Xamarin project now? I have only worked inside Xamarin forms with the nuget-manager so I am a bit unsure on how to proceed with this.

Comment: This example seem to add packages in the nuget straight away in xamarin forms or am I missing something? http://err2solution.com/2016/09/using-microsoft-cognitive-services-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Look at the `packages.config`, do they have the `Face` SDK anywhere other than the PCL? :)

Comment: Another example is the Emotion Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Emotion/ This works fine because it has proper targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add this package to your platform projects. Since this i just a wrapper to access the Cognitive Services APIs it will work directly from the shared code.

The only time you need to install a NuGet on both your shared as well as your platform projects is when it leverages platform specific features. Have a look at the [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) which is included in Xamarin.Forms.

That is basically what those NuGets do, they provide you with an interface to use in your shared code, but under the hood functionality is injected from the platform that you are running on.

In this case there is no need to access platform specific features, so you can just install it on your PCL and it should work.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot for this information. Is there any guides that shows how you can install packages straight to the PCL-project?

Comment: Should I follow this? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/troubleshooting/questions/xs-forms-install/

Comment: There is not really a list, when you get more experienced you will probably be able to spot them. Also, most plugins that need to be installed on the platform project will tell you so on their website. In any case, just install it on your PCL and try running it. It will throw an exception when you forgot to install it on the platform.

Comment: This is the one i need to install to the project: https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-Face-Windows do I add it into my projcets folder or something? Very confused on how to install it properly

Comment: In Xamarin Studio, find the PCL project, right-click the Packages node, find this NuGet package, install it and use it.

Comment: Oh. I misread your first answer completely. I mistakenly thought that I would need to install the package another way.

Comment: Did you misread it? Of maybe it's not clear enough, in that case let me know. I'll try to rewrite it ;) Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: It is perfectly clear :) I just woke up so I blame it on that! Hehe

Comment: I however get another error when I only add the package to the shared project code: `Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face (MT2002)`